# How to control the force of the fluid onto object?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm creating a simulation in which flow of water is impacting on an object. problem is it's not impacting the object as strongly as i want it to. The water is just setting on the object and dripping down the sides. I want it to hit like water does to a spoon when it's being washed. Is there any way of controlling the force of the liquid so that it hits the object more strongly, thus creating a big splash?

Ref: https://www.facebook.com/LADbible/videos/every-time-i-wash-a-spoon-in-the-sink/4464864986893990/

sorry if this has already been asked before or it's a dumb question.

Comment: Is it just a case of setting the Initial Velocity of the fluid inflow so as to give it more force. It would help if you could edit your question to add images of your current setup and results so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using Geometry or Inflow behaviour and allowing gravity to give the fluid momentum you can set the Initial Velocity of the fluid as it enters the simulation to give the fluid more of a 'punch' as it hits the obstacle. Simply enable Initial Velocity and adjust the Initial X,Y,Z components to give it more push in the required direction.

[image: initial velocity]